# Problem in scrolling overlapping tiles in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am building an application with flutter and I have a page with a listView.builder. I wanted the tiles to have some overlapping effect so I used Align. It works fine when I scroll but when I scroll in the opposite direction, the overlapping effect reverses for the tiles that have been out of the screen.
this is a video of what's happening.
pay attention to the top part of the screen when I scroll back.
[image]

this is my code:

HomeScreen:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: SizedFABWidget(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return const CardListViewWidget();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

CardListViewWidget:

```
class CardListViewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> test = [
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '10',
    '11',
    '12',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '10',
    '11',
    '12'
  ];

  CardListViewWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: Get.width,
      height: kBottomListHeight,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: test.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return AlignWidget(
              list: test,
              index: index,
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

AlignWidget:

```
class AlignWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  final List list;

  const AlignWidget({required this.index, required this.list, super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      heightFactor: 0.28,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: kHeight * 0.4,
        child: ListTile(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
            borderRadius: kBorderRadius45,
          ),
          tileColor: getColor(index),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If anything else is needed please let me know and I'll update this post.
thank you in advance.

I almost tried everything I could find on internet and AIs but couldn't solve it, I also don't really understand why this is happening.
I tried Stack and Positioned, Transform.translate and a couple other things but they couldn't solve my problem.
I want my list with overlapping tiles to not change position and don't get behind or come forward, just stay the same as the first few seconds of the video.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This is just a hack and the problem you are facing is that the widgets are being rebuilt. The below solution is not an efficient solution for large lists.

- **Home Screen**

  ```
   class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
       const HomeScreen({super.key});

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
           floatingActionButton: SizedFABWidget(),
           body: SingleChildScrollView(
             child: Column(
               children: [for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) CardListViewWidget()],
             ),
           ),
         );
       }
     }
  ```
- **CardListViewWidget**

  ```
     class CardListViewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
       final List<String> test = [
         '1',
         '2',
         '3',
         '4',
         '5',
         '6',
         '7',
         '8',
         '9',
         '10',
         '11',
         '12',
         '2',
         '3',
         '4',
         '5',
         '6',
         '7',
         '8',
         '9',
         '10',
         '11',
         '12'
       ];

       CardListViewWidget({super.key});

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return SizedBox(
           width: Get.width,
           height: kBottomListHeight,
           child: ListView.builder(
               shrinkWrap: true,
               physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
               itemCount: test.length,
               itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                 return AlignWidget(
                   list: test,
                   index: index,
                 );
               }),
         );
       }
     }
  ```

I hope this helps:)

Comment: thank you, this works for a temporary answer until I find a better solution.